# how DB2 transaction works exactly in concurrent situation

Tags: concurrency, transactions, db2

here are 2 tables employee(empID int,empName varchar,age int) and salary(salID,empID,...).

1. `insert into employee
   select ...
   where not exists (select 1 from employee where empID = :employeeID)`
2. `insert into salary ....`
3. ...

there are 2 jobs running concurrently with above logic and SAME employee.

- job1 failed and rolled back.
- job2 started before job1 rolled back and committed after job1 rolled back.

my questions are:

1. if job2 completed successfully,how many record will be inserted into employee table? 1 or 0?
   more precisely, can step 1 of job2 see the employee record inserted by job1?
2. if 0, how can I make sure the employee is inserted by job2 or won't be removed by job1 rollback?

Comment: Ah, concurrency, the bane of sanity.  The results are largely going to depend on the lock/isolation level chosen - under the 'right' (possibly wrong) level, that subquery is potentially going to lock the _entire table_ which makes it serial, meaning you may as well have just one job (it has to, otherwise you may of course be adding something that fulfills the condition...).  What are you attempting to do here?  Also, storing `age` is going to get you in trouble - how do you know when they get a year older?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If job2 completed successfully, how many records will be inserted into employee table? 1 or 0?

1

> More precisely, can step 1 of job2 see the employee record inserted by job1?

Since you said job1 is rolled back, there is no employee record inserted by job1.

job1 tells the database, "I want to insert an employee record."  DB2 then puts a write lock on the row, page, or table.  When the table was defined, the data base analyst (DBA) made the determination as to what level the table write locks.  The default is page.

As long as the write lock is there, no other transaction can read the insert, unless the read isolation level is uncommitted read.  We'll assume that's not the case here.

job2 has to wait for job1 to commit or rollback before db2 will allow job2 to see job1's row.  After job1 rolls back, the write lock is removed, and job2 is allowed to proceed.

> How can I make sure the employee is inserted by job2 or won't be removed by job1 rollback?

DB2 won't allow job2 to perform the insert until after job1 has been rolled back.

By the way, this sort of problem (two transactions trying to insert the same row) can cause a DB2 deadlock, where both transactions would be rolled back.  Again, this assumes that the transactions (jobs) have a higher read isolation level than uncommitted read.